# Cannot get Dropdownlist to work properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I want a simple dropdownlist that contains the values "Ascending" and "Descending" which are then sent to the controller as sortOrder when the search button is pressed in the Index() method. I have tried so many different things and just cannot get this to work, what am I doing wrong.

P.S I do not want to make this a model, I just want to get back a simple "Asc" or "Desc" from the dropdown into the sortOrder variable.

UserController.cs

```
    public ViewResult Index( string searchString, string sortOrder = "Asc")
    {
        var sortOrderParam = new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Asc", Text = "Ascending" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Desc", Text = "Descending" }
            };

        var users = from u in db.TBL_SYS_USER
                    select u;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            users = users.Where(x => x.USER_FIRST_NAME.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Desc":
                users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.USER_FIRST_NAME);
                break;
            default:
                users = users.OrderBy(u => u.USER_FIRST_NAME);
                break;
        }

        PopulateFieldDropdownList("");

        return View(users.ToList());
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Search Criteria: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
        Order By: @Html.DropDownList("sortOrderParam")

        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller Action, you should create the list of DropDownList options and pass them to your View in a ViewBag, or as a property of your ViewModel. Like below:

```
public ViewResult Index(string searchString, string sortOrder = "Asc")
{
    var users = from u in db.TBL_SYS_USER
                select u;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        users = users.Where(x => x.USER_FIRST_NAME.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "Desc":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.USER_FIRST_NAME);
            break;
        default:
            users = users.OrderBy(u => u.USER_FIRST_NAME);
            break;
    }

    PopulateFieldDropdownList("");

    var sortOrderOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
    sortOrderOptions.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Asc", Text = "Ascending" });
    sortOrderOptions.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Desc", Text = "Descending" });
    ViewBag.SortOrderOptions = sortOrderOptions;

    return View(users.ToList());
}
```

The first argument in `Html.DropDownList` method is the name of the field (which will be the name of the value that will be posted to your Action), and the second one is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which are the options in the DropDownList.
So, your View will look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Search Criteria: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
        Order By: @Html.DropDownList("sortOrderParam", ViewBag.SortOrderOptions)

        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code, I ended up figuring it out:

The Controller:

```
public ViewResult Index(string searchString, string fieldToSearch, string sortOrder = "Asc")
    {
        var sortOrderOptions = new[]
            {
                "Asc",
                "Desc"
            };

        ViewBag.sortOrderList = new SelectList(sortOrderOptions);

        var users = from u in db.TBL_SYS_USER
                    select u;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            users = users.Where(x => x.USER_FIRST_NAME.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Desc":
                users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.USER_FIRST_NAME);
                break;
            default:
                users = users.OrderBy(u => u.USER_FIRST_NAME);
                break;
        }

        PopulateFieldDropdownList("");

        return View(users.ToList());
    }
```

The cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
    Search Criteria: @Html.TextBox("searchString")
    Order By: @Html.DropDownList("sortOrder", ViewBag.sortOrderList as SelectList)
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</p>
}
```